# OpenVPN client on Raspbian (RPi 2B)

Tags: raspbian, vpn

Being not only a Raspberry Pi newcomer and a "Linux virgin", I have been given a Raspberry Pi 2B running Raspbian and which I wish to use it for streaming content from a variety of sources around the world instead of using my laptop when I travel!

I have an account with a VPN supplier who supports OpenVPN and has already received the Cert files from them.

My questions are:

1. Is there an OpenVPN client which can run on a Raspberry Pi 2B
   running Raspbian that I can configure with the cert files from my
   VPN provider myself?
2. If so, what is it called?
3. Where do I find it?
4. Where do I find instructions about how to install- and configure it?

I am always up for a challenge (which is solvable for a person with my relatively limited knowledge - but I can read ;-) )

Any constructive comments are VERY welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that you will get very far streaming on a Pi 2B - even the 4B can struggle with Netflix etc some days and by the time you have carried the Pi, keyboard, mouse and screen you will find a laptop easier.  I carry a Lenovo 120s running Linux on it and it out performs the Pi by miles.

You may do better to [install the OpenVPN server on the PI](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=21237) and leave it at home to allow you back into your network :-)

Saying all of that though, these are from my old notes and may have been changed (not using OpenVPN now) so I'm sorry I've no client handy at the mo and being locked down I could not test it if I build one :-)

To install the client try:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openvpn
cd ~
mkdir openvpn
cd openvpn
```

Put your certificate and key file in here

Find the example config file (client.conf) - it maybe in /usr/share/doc/(directory packages/ maybe here)openvpn/ or below this and copy to this directory

```
cp /usr/share/.../.../.../client.conf .
```

Edit this with `sudo nano client.conf` and change the values to your details for:

- remote (server details space port number)
- ca *(point to your copy of the **ca** file)*
- cert *(again point to your copy of the **client.crt** file)*
- key *(again point to your copy of the **client.key** file)*
- tls-auth *(again point to your copy of the **ta.key** file)*

All paths must be from root and include the file name e.g.

```
ca /home/pi/openvpn/ca.crt
```

Then to start the client:

```
openvpn /home/pi/openvpn/client.conf
```

If you have connection issues try adding either a 0 or 1 **after a space** at the end of the tls-auth. This determines who starts the key exchange - 0 is server, 1 is client and the 1 fixed it for me...

**THE** place for OpenVPN questions is [the OpenVPN Community](https://openvpn.net/community/)

Comment: Thank you Andyroo, I will try thisI use zRam to improve preformance of the PI 2B, - itmake a notable improvement.
I have managed to get OpenVPN running (edited .ovpn files from VPN supplier). Can connet from the terminal, not as userfriendly as from laptop.
Reason for using a RPI is that it is very easy to travel with and easy to connect to the Internet and a TV in any location - e.g. China (where I have experienced to have my laptop checked for VPN), and in this way my wife and I are independant of each other when I take my laptop to a customer meeting and she is cooped up in a hotel room!

Comment: Had a few staff calls from there over Google and VPN issues before today - some strange UK laws impact visits inc HR data being viewed outside the UK boundary etc - good luck on your travels.